# add nodes dynamically to leaf node in D3.js using Tree layout v4 (version 4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treeview

I am working in D3.js Tree Layout Version 3 with https://jsfiddle.net/CJ_Shijo/e7osumLp/ 
example. 
In the jsfiddle example I can hide unrelated parent nodes while clicking on child node. Also I can add nodes dynamically while click on leaf nodes. Below two functions 
are using to add nodes dynamically to leaf nodes.

```
function updateJson(node) {
     var associatedItems = getNewData(node);
     node._children = associatedItems;
     // if the node has visible children, make them invisible
    if (node.children) {
      node._children = node.children;
      node.all_children = node.children;
      node.children = null;
    }
   // if the node has invisible children, make them visible
   else {
      node.children = node._children;
      node.all_children = node._children;
      node._children = null;
  }
  // update the view to reflect the new changes
  if (node.children) {
      node.children.forEach(function (n) {
          n.hidden = false;
      });
      if (node.parent) {
        node.parent.children = [node, ];
        node.parent.hidden = true;
        node.parent.children.filter(function (n) {
            return n !== node;
          }).forEach(function (n) {
              n.hidden = true;
          });
      }
  }

}

 function getNewData(node) {
 /* Return a list of things that will be added as children to the json. */
  return [{
            name: "E",
       }, {
            name: "F",
       }, {
           name: "G",
      }
   ];
}
```

I have achieved this features using d3 V3 version. I need to achieve same features with d3 V4 version.

I started d3 v4 version with this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/CJ_Shijo/km4txwna/ Example.

I have flat json data like below.

```
var flatData = [
  {"name": "Top Level", "parent": null}, 
  {"name": "Level 2: A", "parent": "Top Level" },
  {"name": "Level 2: B", "parent": "Top Level" },
  {"name": "Son Of A", "parent": "Level 2: A" },
  {"name": "Daughter Of A", "parent": "Level 2: A" }
];
```

By using below d3 methods I created hierarchical(tree) data.

```
var treeData = d3.stratify()
                 .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
                 .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
                 (flatData);

  treeData.each(function(d) { d.name = d.id;  }); 
   var root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
```

In the v4 version example I am facing problem on adding nodes dynamically to leaf nodes.Child nodes are not attaching correctly. Can any one help me on the same in V4 version?

Answer (score 3):

following function which is helpful to achieve adding nodes to leaf nodes in d3 v4.

```
    function addNodes(selectedNode) { 

        var data = [{"name":"First"},{"name":"Second"},{"name":"Third"}];

        if (!selectedNode.children) {
                var childArray = [];
             }

        selectedNode.height = selectedNode.height + 1;

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            var obj = d3.hierarchy(d);
            obj.data.parent = selected.name;
            obj.depth = selected.depth + 1;
            obj.parent = selected;
            obj.name = d.name;
            childArray.push(obj);
        });
    selectedNode.children = childArray;
}
```